# Including a hyperlink in a Visual Studio Business Data Connectivity Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am creating a Business Data Connectivity Model in Visual Studio 2010 which will be the source of data for an external list.

I want to include a hyperlink field in this external list, so my model has a SPFieldUrlValue of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue.

However, when I test this model and use it to create an external list this field is not avaliable/does not render.

Question:

A) Am I using the right type by using SPFieldUrlValue
B) Can a business connectivity data model include a link?

This is an example of how I create the link field:

```
        SPFieldUrlValue theLink = new SPFieldUrlValue();
        theLink.Description = "Link Description";
        theLink.Url = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `SPCustomFieldType` instead of the `SPFieldUrlValue`.

There is a nice tutorial on BDC and hyperlinks (and Lookup columns) here: [SharePoint list as source for BDC model: how to handle hyperlink and lookup columns](http://www.eekels.net/sharepoint-list-as-source-for-bdc-model-how-to-handle-hyperlink-and-lookup-columns/).